# Why doesn't AWS ECS Fargate have instance type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

When I configure ECS fargate task, I can configure CPU and Memory value but I can't specify the instance type like `c5.large` etc. The value for CPU is something like 256, 1024, etc. In its price page: https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/pricing/, the price is measured by vCPU which value is 0.5, 1, 2 etc. Is 1024 CPU Units equal to 1 vCPU? Why doesn't Fargate have instance type which will make think easier to understand and consistent? 
If I configure it to be 2048 CPU units + 4 GB memory, does it equal to `c5.large`?

Comment: Fargate is like Lambda. AWS manages its underlying hardware, and you just specify those CPU units and memory.

Comment: Is 1024 CPU unit equal to 1 vCPU?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-cpu) is some explanation. And yes, 1024 is 1 vCPU.

Comment: cool thanks. could you answer it?

Comment: But how fast is that 1 vcpu on fargate? Different EC2 has different CPU spec. See [ec2 instance type](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/).

Comment: my use case is selecting an instance type with faster storage for heavy read/write

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the comments.

[Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/AWS_Fargate.html) is an ECS equivalent of Lambda. You don't manage the instances directly. Instead you choose CPU and the corresponding memory. AWS will take care of provisioning the hardware to meet your specification.

Useful CPU and memory units combinations, as well as their relation to vCPUs is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-cpu):

```
256 (.25 vCPU) - Available memory values: 512 (0.5 GB), 1024 (1 GB), 2048 (2 GB)

512 (.5 vCPU) - Available memory values: 1024 (1 GB), 2048 (2 GB), 3072 (3 GB), 4096 (4 GB)

1024 (1 vCPU) - Available memory values: 2048 (2 GB), 3072 (3 GB), 4096 (4 GB), 5120 (5 GB), 6144 (6 GB), 7168 (7 GB), 8192 (8 GB)

2048 (2 vCPU) - Available memory values: Between 4096 (4 GB) and 16384 (16 GB) in increments of 1024 (1 GB)

4096 (4 vCPU) - Available memory values: Between 8192 (8 GB) and 30720 (30 GB) in increments of 1024 (1 GB)
```

Comment: These are all true, but when someone wants to compare whether to go with ECS or EC2 knowing the actual or equivalent instance type helps to determine how fast is that Fargate machine. (in short, which EC2 instance with 8 vCPU can be as fast as Fargate with 8 vCPU)